# Error code 13 - on import of sqldump

Tags: mysql

Am getting following "permissions" error when trying to import an sqldump

> Error Code: 1 - Can't create/write to file
>      'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\Data\dealcrm\accessorieslink.MYI'
>      (Errcode: 13)

I have renamed the data folder and put it back recently.

Have tried giving full control for user "system" on the data folder - this is user 
the mysql service is started with

any help welcome

EDIT**

Have also tried adding a folder  C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Temp/
and added this line to mysql.ini

```
tmpdir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Temp/"
```

after import there are some files in the folder but still get error 13

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation of the error code](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html), in your particular situation, i.e. on Windows, you're most likely lacking a setting of the right temp directory where MySQL can dump tempfiles. Set it as described in the link above and you should be fine.